# PHP file_exists() not working?

Tags: php, html, file-exists

I am trying to have this script check if an application exists, and if it does, determine whether it is in the "Accepted" or "Denied" section. The two allowed positions are "Mod" and "Admin".

I have the following code on index.php:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="statuscheck.php" method="GET">
            <h1>Is this a mod or admin application?</h1>
            <input type="radio" name="MOA" value="MOD">Mod</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="MOA" value="ADMIN">Admin</input>
            <h1>Put Application ID Below</h1>
            <input type="text" name="APPID" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" /><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Check Status" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This takes the information from the user (to tell `statuscheck.php` where to go ).

Here is `statuscheck.php`

**PHP**

```
<?php
$APPID = $_GET['APPID'];
$MOA = $_GET['MOA'];
$ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

function modCheck() {
    $ACCEPTEDFILEPATH1 = $ROOT . 'public_html/apply/mod-    applications/accepted/' . $APPID . '.php';
    $DENIEDFILEPATH1 = $ROOT . 'public_html/apply/mod-applications/denied/' . $APPID . '.php';
    if (FILE_EXISTS($ACCEPTEDFILEPATH1)) {
        echo 'Your moderator application was accepted';
    } elseif (FILE_EXISTS($DENIEDFILEPATH1)) {
        echo 'Your moderator application was denied';
    } else {
        echo 'Error : Your application ID is incorrect';
    }
}

function adminCheck() {
    $ACCEPTEDFILEPATH2 = $ROOT . 'public_html/admin-applications/accepted/' . $APPID . '.php';
    $DENIEDFILEPATH2 = $ROOT . 'public_html/admin-applications/accepted/' . $APPID . '.php';
    if (FILE_EXISTS($ACCEPTEDFILEPATH2)) {
        echo 'Your admin application was accepted';
    } elseif (FILE_EXISTS($DENIEDFILEPATH2)) {
        echo 'Your admin application was denied';
    } else {
        echo 'Error : Your application ID is incorrect';
    }
}

if ($MOA == "MOD") {
    modCheck();
} elseif ($MOA == "ADMIN") {
    adminCheck();
} else {
    echo 'Please go back and choose mod or admin';
}
```

I have my PHP tags but they won't work on here so I left them out.
Every time I put a valid ID and select "Mod", the code echos

```
Error : Your application ID is incorrect.
```

I do not see anything wrong with my code, and don't understand how it fails the if statements. Can anyone help me ?

**EDIT**
I have set my php variables at the top of `statuscheck.php`, they just won't show up in the code on StackOverflow.

They are:

**PHP**

```
$APPID = $_GET['APPID'];
$MOA = $_GET['MOA'];
$ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: Can you show us what `echo $ACCEPTEDFILEPATH2;` returns? I have a feeling you're doubling up your path and it's not valid.

Comment: who voted to reopen and why; I need specifics here.

Comment: *"EDIT Hey Fred, I don't see how this is a copy of this question."* - `if ($MOA = "MOD") {
    modCheck();
} elseif ($MOA = "ADMIN") {` look at what you're doing here. and tell me that's valid. and don't put that in your question, comment here. remove it please. edit: never mind, I did it for you.

Comment: `=` assignment / `==` comparison. change it to that and if it stills fails, I'll reopen but you'll need to edit your code in the question when you used it.

Comment: It still echos the same thing.

Comment: I have edited the question to what I used so far. The edit changed the = to == at the bottom if statements.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. If so, paste the errors in your question.

Comment: Plus, if you're on a * NIX system, filenames/folders/extensions are case-senstive. So, if you're checking for `APPID-12345.php` and the file is really `appid-12345.php` or `Appid-12345.PHP`, then that will fail; those are 2 different animals altogether. You also have a space in here `mod-    applications` - and make sure your input doesn't contain any whitespace. Use `trim()` if that is the case.

Comment: I have moved on since there isn't any further activity in the question/comments.

Comment: Implementing your suggestions now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98754/discussion-between-burger97979-and-fred-ii).

Comment: I still think theres something fishy in the path, maybe missing a slash or some typo, or permission...